# is there a way to change RASA_NLU config from visual c++ 14.0 to MinGW

Tags: python, tensorflow, rasa-nlu

is there a way to change RASA_NLU config from visual c++ 14.0 to MinGW

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that `C:\MinGW_w64\bin` is in your `PATH` environment variable. Then create a file `distutils.cfg` in the directory `<Python Installation Directory>\Lib\distutils` and add the following content:

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32

[build_ext]
compiler=mingw32
```

Note, that mingw apparently only works with Python versions up to 3.4. See this [wikipage](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#GCC_-_MinGW-w64_.28x86.2C_x64.29) for more information.